# Hall sensor signal error caused speed measurement errors in BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

The three Hall-effect sensors used for BLDC motor speed control are supposed to generate an edge every 60 electrical degrees. however, due to magnet charging problem, or mechanical alignment problem, the edges are often not evenly distributed, which leads to speed detection errors even when the motor is spinning at a constant speed.

My questions are
(1) Is it necessary to calibrate the angle variation between Hall sensor edges in order to minimize the speed detection error? If yes, how to do it? If not, what are the common ways to minimize such error?
(2) If we do calibration, how can I know from which two Hall signal edges are used to detect the speed if there are multiple pole-pairs in one cycle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wouldn't that be dependent on the ESC?

Comment: @jsotola, I am referring to general BLDC controller, not an ESC

Comment: is not every BLDC controller called an ESC?

Comment: @roTor-roTor https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_speed_control